# Patching problems in SLES 12 SP3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sles, zypper

I am trying to patch the SLES 12 SP3 using command `zypper patch`.
Its giving me following problems and options. How should I go about it?

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Patch 'SUSE-SLE-Module-Public-Cloud-12-2020-2135-1' is optional. Use 'zypper in patch:SUSE-SLE-Module-Public-Cloud-12-2020-2135' to install it, or '--with-optional' to include all optional patches.
Resolving package dependencies...
4 Problems:
Problem: nothing provides python3-pyparsing >= 2.0.2 needed by python3-packaging-17.1-2.7.1.noarch
Problem: nothing provides python-cryptography >= 1.5 needed by python-paramiko-2.4.0-9.10.2.noarch
Problem: nothing provides python3-cryptography >= 1.3.4 needed by python3-urllib3-1.25.10-3.29.1.noarch
Problem: nothing provides SUSEConnect > 0.3.31 needed by cloud-regionsrv-client-9.3.0-52.61.2.noarch

Problem: nothing provides python3-pyparsing >= 2.0.2 needed by python3-packaging-17.1-2.7.1.noarch
 Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
  deinstallation of python3-setuptools-40.6.2-4.12.23.noarch
  deinstallation of python3-pyOpenSSL-16.0.0-4.17.1.noarch
  deinstallation of python3-cryptography-1.3.1-7.13.4.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install patch:SUSE-SLE-Module-Public-Cloud-12-2020-3594-1.noarch
 Solution 3: break python3-packaging-17.1-2.7.1.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or skip, retry or cancel [1/2/3/s/r/c] (c):
```

Comment: Can anybody please help me with this

Comment: I need to resolve this on urgent basis, can anyone please look at this issue

Comment: Hello Guys, I need to fix this issue and I did not find any solution for the same. I appreciate if I get help for the same. Thank you.